# 5 CPU's Task scheduling N process

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

**Question.**

> There are 5 CPUs and N number of tasks in the queue. You have to use
>   minimum CPUs to process the tasks.
>
> A task is of format [arrival time, time to process the task].
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1. You can only use at most 5 CPUs. If it is not possible in 5 CPUs, print -1.
> 2. The time to process the task should not be greater than 10     i.e (Time waiting in queue + time to process the task) <= 10.
> 3. If to process the current task, you need more than 10 seconds in current CPU, you can move to a different CPU and check if it is
>      possible to process the task in <=10 time.
> 4. If it is not possible to process the task in <=10 or at most 5 CPUs, print -1.

**Constraints.**

> 0 <= Arrival time <= 500
>
> 1 <= time to process the task <= 10
>
> 0 <= N <=500
>
> You can only use iostream library. No STL's are allowed.
>
> Time : 3 second for T test cases

**Eg:-**

> Input
>
> 3
>
> 1 6
>
> 2 7
>
> 3 1
>
> Output
>
> 2

**Explanation:**

> 3   - N
>
> 1 6 - the first task arrives in CPU0 at time 1, and leaves at time 7 (1+6). 
>    CPUs used = 1.
>
> 2 7 - the second task arrives in CPU0 at time 2, and wait for 5
>   seconds in the queue, so overall processing time is 5+7 > 10. So it is
>   moved to CPU1. CPUs used = 2.
>
> 3 1  -  the third task arrives. it can go to CPU0 or CPU1, as
>   processing time is 5 `( (7-3) + 1 )` and 7 `( (9-3) + 1 )`   seconds respectively. CPUs used = 2.
>
> CPU1 is a fresh CPU. So task2 will be completed in 9 `(2 + 7)` seconds without any Time to wait in the queue.

**My Approach:**

1. Initially, thought this as a variant of `minimum train-platform problem`. But that was wrong.
2. Tried a `greedy` approach, but it gave -1 for some valid solutions.
3. Trying `memoization` approach.

Recursive approach solves the problem, but it gets timed out. (No wonder)

What is the possible way to save the state of `int`, `int`, `int[]`?

I am also open to an iterative solution for the same.

Below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAXN 500

int min_cpus_used = 6;

int N;
int arr[MAXN];
int len[MAXN];

void recurse( int task_idx, int cpus_used_so_far, int  exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[] ){

    if( task_idx == N-1){
        min_cpus_used = min( min_cpus_used, cpus_used_so_far);
        return ;
    }

    if( cpus_used_so_far >= min_cpus_used ){
        return ; //optimization
    }

    for(int i=0; i<cpus_used_so_far ; i++){

        int processing_time = 0;
        int time_in_queue = exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i] - arr[task_idx];

        if( time_in_queue < 0 ) // ie processor is free before arrival
            time_in_queue = 0;

        processing_time = time_in_queue + len[task_idx];

        // try with existing CPUs
        if( processing_time <=10){
            int prev =  exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i];
            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i] = arr[task_idx] + processing_time;

            recurse( task_idx + 1 , cpus_used_so_far , exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs ); // can we optimize passing array

            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[i] = prev;

        }

        // try with new CPU
        if (cpus_used_so_far+1 <= 5){

            int new_cpu_index = cpus_used_so_far + 1 - 1; // converting to zero index

            int prev = exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[new_cpu_index];

            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[new_cpu_index] = arr[task_idx] + len[task_idx] ;

            recurse( task_idx+1 , cpus_used_so_far+1 , exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs );

            exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[new_cpu_index] = prev;

        }else{
            return ;
        }

    }

}



int main(){

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    cin>>N;

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        cin>> arr[i] >> len[i];
    }

    int exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[5]={0};
    recurse(0, 1, exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs);

    if(min_cpus_used==6){
        cout<< -1 <<endl;
    }else{
        cout << min_cpus_used <<endl;
    }

}
```

Kindly help me with your thoughts on optimizing this solution.

Comment: We cannot review this because we accept only real code. Pseudocode is off-topic.

Comment: @t3chb0t I have updated the question with a functional code. Kindly review it.

Comment: See also: [5 CPU's Task scheduling N process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50870973/3789665) over at SO.

Answer (score 3):

Read through and bookmark the [C++ Standard Guidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md).  Numbers I note later are citations from this.

## [Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

```
#define MAXN 500
```

Don't use `#define` for constants or "functions" ([⧺ES.31](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es31-dont-use-macros-for-constants-or-functions)).

---

```
void recurse( int task_idx, int cpus_used_so_far, int  exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[] ){
```

That last parameter is a pointer, with the implication that you are passing a pointer to the first of contiguous elements.  Don’t pass unknown-sized arrays like that.

(Reading ahead…) since it is of fixed size known at compile time, define it as a `std::array` instead, both the actual array in `main` and the parameter (by reference).

---

```
int min_cpus_used = 6;

int exit_time_of_task_in_CPUs[5]={0};

if (cpus_used_so_far+1 <= 5){

if(min_cpus_used==6){
```

Hard-coded magic numbers: are these all related?  Define a constant instead of sprinkling these throughout the code.

---

Let’s see… `cpus_used_so_far` is not changed within the function, just passed a different value when recursing, right?  It would be helpful for readability and analysis to mark it `const` in the declaration.

```
    if (cpus_used_so_far+1 <= 5){
            ⋮
    }else{
        return ;
    }
```

That took me a moment to figure out what the `else return` was doing at the end of the function just before the closing braces.  This would be much clearer if you invert the logic:  put the exceptional case first, in the manner of precondition testing.

```
if (cpus_used_so_far+1 > 5)  return;
⋮
```

Note that there is no further indenting of the regular code, since it is not nested anymore — it is the main-line of code.

---

```
cin.tie(NULL);
```

Don’t use the C macro `NULL`.  For a null pointer, it is the keyword `nullptr`.

```
    cout<< -1 <<endl;
```

Don’t use `endl`.  Just use `\n`.